# WinForm Class open as class instead of design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I was working on a WinForm, and for an unknow reason, I can't open it in design mode anymore, any (only that specific form). Is there anyway to tell Visual Studio 2013 that it's a WinForm and not a Class ?

[image]

Comment: Did you delete/rename the designer.cs file?

Comment: nop, the designer file is there.

Comment: Do you have your form class correctly derive from the Form class?

Comment: It's derived from a BaseForm I have. I tried to derive it directly from System.Windows.Forms.Form, still nothing.

Comment: Oh well, the class magically came back to normal. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "unload" the project, and then edit the .csproj file. Search for your .cs file, and insert a SubType node...     `<Compile Include="Scraper.cs"><SubType>Component</SubType></Compile>`. Save the .csproj and Reload your project.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had a class defined before the partial class, i.e.:

```
public class MyClass { ... }
public partial class MyForm : Form { ... }
```

Defining MyClass after MyForm fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same happens to me, when I did some base class for my forms and manually change to it in generated forms.

Solution was to add

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Form")]
```

attribute to base class definition.

P.S.: same way around, you can use

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
```

if you want some own derived control to never open in designer, like if it is a user conhtrol.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your file in Solution Explorer, "Open with.." and reselect the designer in the list. Maybe? Or maybe your Designer.cs file has an issue or was somehow corrupted as mentionned by the replier above.

Comment: Designer is not in the list

Comment: Hmm. don't really know, are the properties (Visual Studio, ALT+Enter) of the file the same as the other forms in your solution? In case of "strange" and severe Visual Studio issues, I tend to delete the .suo file next to the .sln and try again. Suo stores a tons of little mighty things that may end up with weird issues in VS, just a hint..

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the Form inheritance after your form class you experience the behaviour described

```
 public partial class MyMainForm : Form
 {

 }
```

here, if you remove the inheritance from the base Form class Visual Studio shows your form code instead of the designer when you double click on the form name in the Solution Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespaces match on the form class `StateRuleDetailTriggerForm.cs` and its designer class `StateRuleDetailTriggerForm.Designer.cs`.